# Table not mapped [FROM Table]

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to make a query to the database and I get this:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: generalsetup is
>   not mapped [FROM generalsetup]
>     org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133)
>     org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
>     org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
>     org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:670)
>     org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:103)
>     org.apache.jsp.Environments_jsp._jspService(Environments_jsp.java:188)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

**IMPORTANT:** I can write to the database but I can't read.

This is my code that tries to get a list from (I have a error mark under `generalsetup`:

```
SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.GetSessionFactory();
Session hibernateSession = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = hibernateSession.beginTransaction();
    List environments = hibernateSession.createQuery("FROM generalsetup").list();
    for (Iterator iterator = environments.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Environment environment = (Environment) iterator.next();
        System.out.println(environment.getName());
    }
    tx.commit();
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    hibernateSession.close();
}
```

My GeneralSetup.hbm.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.atp.servlets.Model.GeneralSetup" table="generalsetup">
        <meta attribute="class-description">
            This class contains the general_setup detail.
        </meta>
        <id name="id" type="int" column="idGeneralSetup">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
        <property name="hasProfile7" column="hasProfile7" type="boolean"/>
        <property name="hasWebAdmin" column="hasWebAdmin" type="boolean"/>
        <property name="hasWebClient" column="hasWebClient" type="boolean"/>
        <property name="hasWebCSR" column="hasWebCSR" type="boolean"/>
        <property name="profile7Branch" column="profile7Branch" type="string"/>
        <property name="webAdminBranch" column="webAdminBranch" type="string"/>
        <property name="webClientBranch" column="webClientBranch" type="string"/>
        <property name="webCSRBranch" column="webCSRBranch" type="string"/>
        <property name="initialDayEnd" column="initialSystemDate" type="string"/>
        <property name="finalDayEnd" column="finalSystemDate" type="string"/>
        <property name="amountOfDayEnds" column="amountOfDayEnds" type="int"/>
        <property name="user" column="user" type="string"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>

        <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            root
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
            qetwr123
        </property>

        <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="com/atp/servlets/Model/GeneralSetup.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Try to use : `hibernateSession.createQuery("FROM com.atp.servlets.Model.GeneralSetup ").list();` instead

Comment: Also use proper casing. It's not `generalsetup`, it's `GeneralSetup`.

Comment: @Kayaman the table on mysql is `generalsetup`

Comment: But you're supposed to use the name of the entity, not the name of the table. It's not SQL.